# invalid grant pops up while sending Gmail in nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, oauth, gmail

When I send mail then, it successfully sends the mail. But after a few days, it says 'invalid_grant'. Then when I again generate a new refresh token from `https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground` and use it, it works again. So what's the problem that access token doesn't work after few days.

```
const GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
const GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
const GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI = process.env.GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI
const GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN = process.env.GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN

const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI)
oAuth2Client.setCredentials({refresh_token: GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN})

export async function sendMail(payload: IMailDTO): Promise<SMTPTransport.SentMessageInfo>{
    const data = MailDTO.receiver(payload)
    const accessToken = await oAuth2Client.getAccessToken()

    const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        // @ts-ignore
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            type: 'OAUTH2',
            user: 'user@gmail.com',
            clientId: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
            refreshToken: GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN,
            accessToken,
        }
    })
    
    const mailOptions = {
        from: 'no-reply <no-reply@gmail.com>',
        to: data.to,
        subject: data.subject,
        text: data.text,
        html: data.html
    }

    let result = await transport.sendMail(mailOptions)
    
    if(!result){
        throw new Error("Email not sent. Try again.")
    }

    return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with your access token the issue is with your refresh token.

The first is the OAuth Playground will automatically revoke refresh tokens after 24h. You can avoid this by specifying your own application OAuth credentials using the Configuration panel.

The second being that if you have supplied your own OAuth Credentials and your application is still in testing then it will expire after seven days.

> A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.

To have a refresh token that will not expire you need to create it using your own credentials and make sure to set your application in production.